# Opa chat app not working

Tags: opa

I copied opa chat application. It's working on OSX Lion but not on my 32 bit linux machine. I know that 32 bit is not supported but I was able to compile opa. I then compiled chat app. When I access it, I get the initial page but when I add some text to chat, that text is not displayed.

I don't know how to debug this. I have increased the verbosity to 8. What else can I do to debug this?

Thanks
Prabhat Gupta

Comment: 32 bits is not supported, not because MLstate does not have 32bits machines, but because le compiler does not generate valid code on 32bits. Hence, no surprise you have unexpected behavior here.

Comment: Agreed with Hugo. We're working on a 32-bit port but we're also hard at work on many other features so hard to say when we will be able to release it...

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Hugo, 32 bits is not officially supported. However, from your experience, this seems to be an accessible goal. If you want to debug the issue, that is actually provide a 32 bits port of Opa, then the Opa team is willing to encourage and support you!

In your case, the interesting output log is probably in a file error.log at the path where you launched your chat app. But you can have more logs. When you compile from sources without passing the -release flag to ./configure, you have access to a lot of shell environment variables that trigger debug logs (or alter the behavior of the compiler). They are all listed in libbase/debugVariables.mli (all variables are named MLSTATE_SOMETHING_IN_UPPER_CASE). There is also a command-line tool called mlset that is installed by make install (maybe make install-all) that may help.

A first step to debug is to set MLSTATE_SHOW_LOGS=1, then maybe some other relevant flags. I would advise to pick first some of MLSTATE_SESSION_DEBUG, MLSTATE_HTTP_DEBUG, MLSTATE_PING_DEBUG (set them to higher values).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I can get more info with the env variable you mentioned. 

I just used Firefox instead of Google Chrome and chat is working. So here is the final situation:

Use Os X release:

Google chrome: Chat app works
Fireforx: did not try 

32 bit on Linux (ubuntu 11.04). compiled from source

Google chrome: chat body where messages are displayed doesn't show up.
Firefox: Works as expected.

I will try to debug this. Any hints are welcome.

I can try to make a 32 bit port for ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I can get more info with the env variable you mentioned.  <br/>  <br/>

I just used Firefox instead of Chrome and chat is working. Final situation:  <br/>  <br/>

Use Os X release:  <br/>  <br/>

Google chrome: Chat app works  <br/>
Fireforx: did not try  <br/>  <br/>

32 bit on Linux (ubuntu 11.04), compiled from source:  <br/>  <br/>

Google chrome: chat body where messages are displayed doesn't show up  <br/>
Firefox: Works as expected  <br/>  <br/>

I will try to debug this. Any hints are welcome.  <br/>  <br/>

I can try to make a 32 bit port for ubuntu.