# How do I compile Opa in 32-bit Ubuntu?

Tags: opa

I've been working on getting Opa to compile under 32-bit Ubuntu 11.10. Today I found a thread on Stack Overflow where Prabhat Gupta claimed to have gotten it to compile on his 32-bit Linux machine. (The thread in question is titled [Opa chat app not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479755/opa-chat-app-not-working))

I would have loved to ask him how he did this, but unfortunately I couldn't find any way to get in contact with him. My question: have you succeeded in what I'm trying to do? If so, how did you manage to do it? I'd really like to get Opa working on 32-bit systems, but I don't want to duplicate other people's work if I can help it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try http://doc.opalang.org/index.html#_building_opa_from_the_sources?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OPA now supports 32 bits but we do not provide a binary yet.

You can compile it from the source code : https://github.com/MLstate/opalang

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. I'll definitely do that and provide you guys with some feedback. :-)